# How to create two pages from a same module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I already have a page when I created a new module. Now, I'm trying to create a new another pages in this module. How can I do that? Which files do I need?
Really hope that anyone can help. Thanks.
I already have this page:

[image]

So, when I click on *"Order Detail"*, I want to move to another page (page_detail). The problem I having is how to create the *Page detail* in this module?

Comment: Please upload your files code for first page.

Comment: Hi @Rohan, I have updated my question, please check.